# Custom module that can define and have settings referenced (Craft 3)

Tags: craft3, plugins, modules

I'm currently working on migrating a Craft 2 project which has a bunch of bespoke custom plugins that provided various bits of additional functionality that's tailored to this project only. I've been reading up on the recommended approach in Craft 3 and have understood that modules are better suited in a lot of cases.

However, I've come across a snag with a previous Craft 2 plugin, that basically existed to provide settings that could be referenced in PHP/Twig. This plugin implemented various settings that were defined at `config/mycustompluginhandle.php`.

I'd like to have the same again but as a module, but it looks like the settings model isn't the same as a plugin and you have to "roll your own" setup for this.

My question is can is a module provide settings via a `config/something.php` file and can these settings be referenced in other parts of the application i.e. PHP/Twig or another plugin/module? If so, how can I go about doing achieving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on a bit of research. I don't think you necessarily have to create a settings model, if the settings are purely required from a config file. You could use something like:

```
$settings = Craft::$app->config->getConfigFromFile('configfilename');
$exampleSettings = $settings['exampleSomething'];
```

`$settings` would be an array, which you could then access each array key.